# Fastest way to count occurences of a substrings list in ruby

Tags: ruby, algorithm, optimization, substring

My problem is simple, I have a list of substrings, and I have to count how many substrings are included in a specific string.
Here is my code :

```
string = "..."
substrings = ["hello", "foo", "bar", "brol"]
count = 0
substrings.each do |sub|
    count += 1 if string.include?(sub)
end
```

In this example, we run through the entire string 4 times, which is quite consuming.
How would you optimize this process ?

Answer (score 7):

This uses a [`Regexp.union`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html#method-c-union) to run through the string only once:

```
string = 'hello there! this is foobar!'
substrings = ["hello", "foo", "bar", "brol"]

string.scan(Regexp.union(substrings)).count
# => 3
```

Though this solution is markedly slower with small input, it has lower complexity - for string of length `n` and substrings of length `m` the original solution has a complexity of `O(m*n)`, while this solution has a complexity of `O(m+n)`.

---

**Update**
After reading the question again, and my answer, I've come to the conclusion that not only this is a premature optimization (as @Max has noted), but that my answer is semantically *different* than the OP.

Let me explain - the OP code counts how many of the `substrings` has *at least one* appearance in the string, while my solution count *how many appearances* are there for *any* of the `substrings`:

```
op_solution('hello hello there', ["hello", "foo", "bar", "brol"])
# => 1
uri_solution('hello hello there', ["hello", "foo", "bar", "brol"])
# => 2
```

This also explains why my solution is so slow, even for long strings - although it has only one pass on the input string, it has to pass *all* of it, while the original code stops at the first occurrence of a word.

My conclusion is - go with @Arup's solution. It will not be faster than yours, it is just more succinct, but I can't think of anything better :)

Comment: I am curious to see a benchmark for when this starts to overtake the naive O(mn) algorithm. This smells a bit like a premature optimization.

Comment: Maybe sort the string and use dichotomy ?

Comment: You are assuming your substrings are single, whole words?

Answer (score 3):

write as :-

```
substrings.count { |sub| string.include?(sub) }
```

Comment: This actually does not run any faster than the OP code (although it is more beautifully written)

Comment: This runs faster than the string.scan (according to Benchmark) ... string.scan came up about 18 times slower.

Comment: @SteveTurczyn - the problem here is more of a complexity - as the string gets longer, and substrings get larger, this solution takes `O(m*n)`, while the scan solution has a complexity of `O(m+n)`

Comment: @UriAgassi How about `substrings.count { |sub| string[sub] }` ?

Comment: That's exactly the same - for each substring (`m` times) it goes over the _whole_ string (`n` length) which gives complexity of `O(m*n)`. It is more succinct than your original answer, and very idiomatic for ruby, but the runtime is (essentially) the same.

Comment: @UriAgassi Ohhh :( :(

Answer (score 0):

`subtrings.collect { |i| string.scan(i).count }.sum`

Elegant.